# Finding the dimension indexes of elements of an array

Tags: arrays, r

Consider this array:

```
the.seq <- 1:4
sol<- outer(outer(the.seq, the.seq, `+`), the.seq, `+`)
```

I want to find all elements that sum 6. That is pretty easy to do with `which`:

```
indices <- which(sol == 6)
indices
 [1]  4  7 10 13 19 22 25 34 37 49
```

Now I want a vector with the dimension indexes of these elements, the answer would be:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    4    1    1
 [2,]    3    2    1
 [3,]    2    3    1
 [4,]    1    4    1
 [5,]    3    1    2
 [6,]    2    2    2
 [7,]    1    3    2
 [8,]    2    1    3
 [9,]    2    1    3
[10,]    1    1    4
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `arr.ind` argument in `which`.  When set to `TRUE`, `which` will return the array indices for which its first argument is `TRUE`.

```
which(sol == 6, arr.ind = TRUE)
#      dim1 dim2 dim3
# [1,]    4    1    1
# [2,]    3    2    1
# [3,]    2    3    1
# [4,]    1    4    1
# [5,]    3    1    2
# [6,]    2    2    2
# [7,]    1    3    2
# [8,]    2    1    3
# [9,]    1    2    3
#[10,]    1    1    4
```

Comment: Yep, it's very convenient.